# Do you think its worth to make one more classes from an "observer" object?

Tags: php, observer-pattern

there are `news` and `newsTranslations`. Every time a `new` is created, at least one `translation` should be exists:

```
class NewsModel
{
    public function add()
    {
        $newId = SQL INSERT INTO NEWS
        $this->notifyAdd ($newId);
    }
}

class NewsTranslationModel
{
    public function add ($newId)
    {
        SQL INSERT INTO
    }

    public function notifyAdd($newId)
    {
        $this->add ($newId);
    }
}

$news = new NewsModel();
$newsTranslation = new NewsTranslationModel();
$news->attach ($newsTranslation);
```

but in that way, I feel that `NewsTranslationModel` has too much responsibilities. What if I write this:

```
class NewsModel
{
    public function add()
    {
        $newId = SQL INSERT INTO NEWS
        $this->notifyAdd ($newId);
    }
}

class NewsTranslationModel
{
    public function add ($newId)
    {
        SQL INSERT INTO
    }
}

class NewsTranslationObserver
{
    private $newsTranslation;

    public function __constructor ($newsTranslation)
    {
         $this->newsTranslation = $newsTranslation;
    }

    public function notifyAdd($newId)
    {
        $this->newsTranslation->add ($newId);
    }
}

$news = new NewsModel();
$newsTranslation = new NewsTranslationModel();
$news->attach (new NewsTranslationObserver($newsTranslation));
```

what do you think? Is this a better approach? Because I saw many examples but nowhere I saw this separating